# How to reserve the exact text size for the next frame

Tags: beamer, siunitx, animate, parbox

how to reserve the exact size of the response text for the next frame (when I use siunitx and animateinline combined).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Exemplos de Conversão}
        \large

        Vamos realizar as seguintes conversões: \vspace{0.2cm}

        \begin{animateinline}[controls,buttonsize=1em,step]{2}

            $\SI{100}{\deca\meter} \longrightarrow  \parbox[c]{3cm}{\rule{2cm}{\fill} \SI{}{\centi\meter}} $
            \newframe
            $\SI{100}{\deca\meter} \longrightarrow \parbox[c]{3cm}{ \SI{100000}{\centi\meter}}$

        \end{animateinline}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! You can use `eqparbox` for that. I added

```
\eqmakebox[A][r]{\SI{}{\centi\meter}}
```

and

```
\eqmakebox[A][r]{\SI{100000}{\centi\meter}}
```

where `A` is an id, i.e. all boxes tagged `A` will have the same width, and `r` is the alignment. You need to compile this twice to write the widths in the aux file, and use the maximum in the second run.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Exemplos de Convers\~ao}
        \large

        Vamos realizar as seguintes convers\~oes: \vspace{0.2cm}

        \begin{animateinline}[controls,buttonsize=1em,step]{2}

            $\SI{100}{\deca\meter} \longrightarrow  \eqmakebox[A][r]{\SI{}{\centi\meter}}  $
            \newframe
            $\SI{100}{\deca\meter} \longrightarrow \eqmakebox[A][r]{\SI{100000}{\centi\meter}}$

        \end{animateinline}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool package, thank you for mentioning eqparbox.

Comment: @AlexG It is a useful package. I also allows us to have columns of a Ti*k*Z matrix left- or right-aligned, and so on.

Comment: Great. Perfect solution!